# angular 5- define language in google mpas api

Tags: angular, google-maps

am using this tutorial to add google maps to my angular 5 project:
https://blog.cloudboost.io/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-5-ca5f68009f29

and i wont to define a hebrew language to the map. But I can not find where to set it.

i try like this:

```
var mapProp = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.084573, 34.802909),
  zoom: 18,
  language: "he",
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

But it's not working. 
someone knows where to set the language?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the language via the link to the api:

For example Hebrew:

```
<script 
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?language=he&dir='rtl'"      
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As mentioned in the comments by @mxr7350, see this link for closer info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language

For Hebrew you might need to pass `&dir='rtl'` as well, because the text goes from right to left instead from left to right

Comment: might be worth attaching official docs as well
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language

Comment: you're right @mxr7350 Thanks, I added it to the answer

Comment: @levi no worries. add this answer as solution if it helped fixing your problem pls (: